# Error message when using lrm() and validate() from the rms package

Tags: r, ordered-logit, error-message

I do not have a fully reproducible  example as I am using proprietary data. Therefore, I am providing here an example that only partially reproduces the problem.

I am trying to fit an ordinal logistic regression via `lrm()`. For instance:

```
TV <- c(rep(1:7, each = 100), 8) #TV is target variable
PD <- c(rep(1:7, each = 100), 8) * runif(length(TV)) #PD is predictor

DT <- data.table(TV, PD)

lrm.model <- lrm(TV ~ PD, 
                 x = T,
                 y = T,
                 data = DT,
                 maxit = 1000)
```

When I try to test this model through resampling with `validate()` as follows:

```
validate(lrm.model, B = 200, bw = F)
```

I get an error as a result of the number '8' in the `TV` column:

```
Error in predab.resample(fit, method = method, fit = lrmfit, measure = discrim,  : 
  A training sample has a different number of intercepts (14)
than the original model fit (15).
You probably fit an ordinal model with sparse cells and a re-sample
did not select at least one observation for each value of Y.
Add the argument group=y where y is the response variable.
This will force balanced sampling on levels of y.
```

So I added `group = TV` to the `validate()` function:

```
validate(lrm.model, group = TV, B = 200, bw = F)
```

Which solves the problem.

On my actual data, however, I then get another error:

```
Error in predab.resample(fit, method = method, fit = lrmfit, measure = discrim,  : 
  object 'TV' not found
```

Do you have any idea what the issue could be?